# Can I run an ASP.NET MVC2 website with a database from the iPad locally? (iPhone)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, ipad, xamarin.ios

I really want to run my test websites from an iPad to show to clients but I don't want to have to rely on the 3g connectivity or wifi. Can I run sites that are compiled from an App or something similar on the iPad?

I have seen [Mono Touch](http://monotouch.net/) but I wanted first hand views on this as if I can I'm going to buy an iPad ASAP.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Service Stack](http://www.servicestack.net/) to create web services.  I'm sure you can serve up HTML one way or another.  I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is IIS or Cassini for the iPad, which doesn't exist, as far as I know.

Using MonoTouch, you'd have to create a native app that simply functioned as a browser shell and served up HTML. MVC works in Mono, so you *could* do it using a local db, but it would be a lot of work, and I'm not sure what that would buy you... Other than an iPad, which just might make the effort worth it. :)

Comment: I just want to show demo websites on it because fancy products (iPad) help sell things :)

Guess I may have to go for 3G and hope the connection works so I don't turn up looking like a tool with a gadget that wont do the job :)

Comment: Or you could have a laptop with an ad-hoc Wifi connection to the iPad server the pages.

Comment: yer we did that at work the other day but I want to not have to rely on the intermittant phone network around certain areas :)

Comment: Oh, totally. I love the idea. Use the iPad to demo the site, and the iPad sells the site. I think as long as you let cutomers know you need at least a decent wireless signal, or Wifi access, you should be good. That, and use ASP.NET Caching, script minifaction, etc. to make your site as snappy as possible. Good luck!

Comment: Cheers! Will Post some lovely photos soon :p

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, a bit of a hack, but extending waht ifwdev said, if you can expose services as JSON endpoints, you could mock the UI using raw HTML and Javascript instead of server side code (PHP/ASP.NET etc).